# Functional programming in Scala: Output the word (or list of words) that occurs the most times in the text file?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Output the word (or list of words) that occurs the most times in the text file (irrespective of case – i.e. “word” and “Word” are treated the same for this purpose). We are only interested in words that contain alphabetic characters [A-Z a-z], so ignore any digits (numbers), punctuation, etc.

If there are several words that occur most often with equal frequency then all these words should be printed as a list. Alongside the word(s) you should output the number of occurrences. For example:

The word(s) that occur most often are [“and”, “it”, “the”] each with 10 occurrences in the text.

I have the following code:

```
val counter: Map[String, Int] = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines
      .flatMap(_.split("[^-A-Za-z]+")).foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
      (count, word) => count + (word.toLowerCase -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
    }
    val list = counter.toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse
```

This goes as far as creating a list of the words in descending order of occurrences. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: You don't need to to sort, rather just find the maximum number of occurrences and then use `filter` to get all words with that number of occurrences, then you can just print.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are almost there ...

```
   val maxNum = counter.headOption.fold(0)(_._2) // What's the max number?
   list
     .iterator // not necessary, but makes it a bit faster to perform chained transformations
     .takeWhile(_._2 == maxNum) // Get all words that have that count
     .map(_._1) // drop the counts, keep only words
     .foreach(println) // Print them out
```

One kinda major problem with your solution is that you shouldn't *sort* the list just to find the maximum, as pointed out in the comment.
Just do

```
    val maxNum = counter.maxByOption(_._2).fold(0)(_._2)
    counter
     .iterator
     .collect { case (w, `maxNum`) => w }
     .foreach(println)
```

Also, a bit of a "cosmetic" improvement to your counting is to use `groupMapReduce` that does what you've accomplished with `foldLeft` a bit more elegantly:

```
    val counter = source.getLines
        .flatMap("\\b") // \b is a regex symbol for "word boundary"
        .filter(_.contains("\\w")) // filter out the delimiters - you have a little bug here, that results in your counting spaces as "words"
        .groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _) // group data by word, replace each occurrence of a word with `1`, and add them all up
```